# How to get x value where area under curve is some number?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, inverse

My goal is to get x value where area under the curve (from the x ~ infinity) is about 0.05. But the code which I have tried shows errors. How to correct it?

```
Solve[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(x\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-x\)/2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3/2\)]\), \(3\ 
\*SqrtBox[\(2\ \[Pi]\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) == 0.05, x]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your integral has a closed form solution, so take that and give it a name:

```
g[x_] := 1/3 E^(-x/2) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[x] (3 + x) + Erfc[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]]
```

One way to find the value of x where g[x]==0.05 is to solve:

```
Minimize[Abs[(g[x] - 0.05)^2] && x \[Element] Reals, x]
{2.92244*10^-18, {x -> 11.0705}}
```

Comment: "Closed-form" is perhaps a generous way of describing the error function.

Comment: @Michael Seifert -- if you prefer... a solution in terms of well-defined functions!

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your integral is the complement of the [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html) for a [`GammaDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaDistribution.html).

```
dist = GammaDistribution[5/2, 2];

pdf[x_] = PDF[dist, x]

(* Piecewise[{{x^(3/2)/(E^(x/2)*(3*Sqrt[2*Pi])), x > 0}}, 0] *)
```

The integral is

```
int[x_] = Assuming[x > 0, 1 - CDF[dist, x] // Simplify]

(* 1 - GammaRegularized[5/2, 0, x/2] *)
```

While [`GammaRegularized`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaRegularized.html) can be "simplified" to the result given by `bill s`

```
int[x] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* 1/3 E^(-x/2) Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] (3 + x) + Erfc[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]] *)
```

It is easier to deal with `GammaRegularized` and its inverse. The exact solution is

```
a = x /. Solve[{int[x] == 1/20, x > 0}, x][[1]]

(* 2 InverseGammaRegularized[5/2, 0, 19/20] *)
```

The approximate numeric value is

```
a // N

(* 11.0705 *)
```